# How do I set Proxy in Raspberry Pi - Raspbian OS (or any Linux) using Command Line?

Tags: raspbian, networking

I'm using my college network.Here i have set proxy to 10.30.0.1:8080 to access internet.But i'm not able to set proxy in Raspberry Pi 3.

Comment: this question has been answered in another stackexchange post[Proxy settings for Raspbian Jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/proxy-settings-for-raspbian-jessie/80313#80313)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### For apt:

Navigate to the following folder as follows:

`cd /etc/apt/apt.conf.d`

Create a file called `10proxy`:

`sudo nano 10proxy`

Without authentication add this line:

`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://proxyaddress:proxyport/";`

Or with authentication add this line:

`Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@proxyaddress:proxyport/";`

Make sure to include the `/` at the end.

### For everything else:

Edit this file:

`sudo nano /etc/environment`

Add this line (with authentication):

`export http_proxy="http://username:password@proxyaddress:port/"`

Or without authentication:

`export http_proxy="http://proxyaddress:port/"`

Comment: Does this set the http_proxy and https_proxy environment variables?  Or does this only setup a proxy for `apt`?

Comment: I made a mistake! See my edited answer for the full solution

Comment: The method for apt is working.But for everything else: method is not working.Can you tell me that what do you mean by 'host in 'export http_proxy="http://host:port/" ? I have tried by putting Proxy Address 10.30.0.1:8080 but it is not working. @Veroxi .Thanks for previous answer.

Comment: `host` should be **just** the IP (not the port)

Comment: yes i'm not putting port here.I have used only ip 10.30.0.1.But it is not working?Have you tested this earlier?

Comment: is there any difference between host and proxyaddress? IP address of my raspberry pi is 192.168.1.2

Comment: No, host and proxyaddress are the same

Comment: Updated this answer to replace the word "host" with "proxyaddress" in case anyone is confused with the local host.

Comment: and how do I do it with https?

Answer (score 3):

As of Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster), the syntax for defining environment variables has changed from the older syntax shown in other answers. The `export` keyword is no longer supported in the `/etc/environment` file, and causes errors like this:

> invalid variable name "export http_proxy", ignoring.

Edit `/etc/environment` and set 3 lines to proxy both secure insecure requests:

```
http_proxy="http://username:password@proxyaddress:port/"
https_proxy="http://username:password@proxyaddress:port/"
no_proxy="localhost,127.0.0.1"
```

Restart the system for changes to take effect. After rebooting, open a terminal and type the following to see if the variables are present:

```
env | grep proxy
```

Note that Chromium (the default browser) often caches pages even on a "hard refresh," so your proxy settings may not appear to work. Use an incognito window to open a test site.

Answer (score 2):

The proxy on any Linux environment can be set using two files

> 1. /etc/environment
> 2. /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy (sometimes this file doesnt exist so create one)

now firstly see what are the default setting in these two files using cat command

> 1.cat /etc/environment ==> create a backup if something goes wrong
>
> 2.cat /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/01proxy

using a simple bash script you can disable or enable proxy for terminal written by me : https://github.com/k1941996/Proxy_switcher/blob/master/switch_proxy.txt

simply change the proxy according to your network.

Add these files in your .bashrc file and you can directly switch proxy using simple commands like enableproxy and disableproxy