# Proxy settings for Raspbian Jessie

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, raspbian-jessie, internet

I just borrowed a Raspberry Pi 2 from my friend.

As my institute has a proxy server with user authentication, I can't access the internet via my Pi. I installed Raspbian Jessie.

I need help to solve this

Comment: This is not really about the Pi, but rather the network settings required to access the internet, from any device.

Comment: i know how to config my pc and other devices. only facing problem while configuring raspberry pi 2. i didnt find any option for proxy settings. @Greenonline

Comment: You need to edit and clarify your question in that case, because as it reads currently, it seems that you only require the proxy settings that your institute uses.  The more information that you provide, and the clearer that your question is, the more likely it is that someone will be able to help you and provide you with an accurate answer, that you will find useful. What have you tired and what doesn't work, for example. Have you tried [google](https://www.google.co.th/search?q=proxy+settings+jessie+pi)? Does the first link help?

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have to authenticate, add the following lines to the following files:

   For general browsing, in `/etc/environment` add

   ```
   export http_proxy="http://username:password@host:port/"
   ```

   For `apt-get`, in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10proxy` add

   ```
   Acquire::http::Proxy "http://username:password@host:port";
   ```
2. If you *do not* have to authenticate, add the following lines to the following files:

   For general browsing, in `/etc/environment` add

   ```
   export http_proxy="http://host:port/"
   ```

   For `apt-get`, in `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10proxy` add

   ```
   Acquire::http::Proxy "http://host:port/";
   ```

Source: [Connect Raspi to a Proxy](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=18634)

Comment: i tried this before but not working.. :(

Comment: @TanmayYerunkar - You are still being extremely vague... *What* exactly is not working? The Pi is not powering up??? What are you trying to do? Web browsing, `apt`, telnet, what exactly? If you tried this already, then why did you not say so in your question, in order to save people having to fish around trying to understand exactly what your issue is? If you are not more specific then your question will be closed, as it is very unclear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

To connect proxy on raspi you need to add proxy at 3 places namely

1. `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/10proxy` and then type

   `Acquire::http::Proxy
   “http://username:password@proxy_server_address:port/”;`
2. `/etc/environment` and then type

   `export http_proxy=”http://username:password@proxy_server_address:port/”`
3. `~/.bashrc` and then type

   `export http_proxy=http://username:password@proxy_server_address:port`

Source: [TheAILearner, Connecting Raspberry pi to proxy server](https://theailearner.com/2018/03/13/connecting-raspberry-pi-to-proxy-server/)