# How can I connect my Pi to a proxy server to download packages?

Tags: raspbian

My Pi has Raspbian Jessie and it is behind my college's proxy server. I am not able connect to the internet and download packages. How can I connect to the proxy server and access the Internet?

Comment: the same has been answered for this stackexchange question[Proxy settings for Raspbian Jessie](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/proxy-settings-for-raspbian-jessie/80313#80313)

Answer (score 1):

You can find instructions on configuring `apt`, the package manager, to use a proxy [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptGet/Howto#Setting_up_apt-get_to_use_a_http-proxy).  Your best option is probably to create a file `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/90proxy` containing:

```
Acquire::http::Proxy "http://yourproxyaddress:proxyport";
```

Your web browser should have it's own proxy configuration.  For example, see:

- [Firefox](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/992282)